# dialogflow hangouts chat integration no response using actions-sdk

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, google-hangouts

When connecting dialogflow with hangouts chat I am getting normal responses set in dialogflow. But messages from the webhook running on google actions sdk is not  returning messages.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
const {dialogflow, BasicCard, Permission, Suggestions,} = require('actions-on-google');
app.intent('id', (conv, {name}) =>
 {
  conv.close(`People here are always available.So,you can call ${name} anytime`)
});
```

This works with google assistant and webchat. Only with Google chat the response is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions-on-google library only works with the Google Assistant.

For other integrations, including Facebook, Slack, and Hangouts Chat, you need to either use the dialogflow-fulfillment library, or respond with JSON directly.